# placement of 'per year' in a sentence

Tags: syntactic-analysis, sentence-patterns

In the first sentence, the term ‘**per year**’ is placed within the sentence and in the second sentence, at the end.

Which pattern is correct and which one is wrong?

> 1. The business purchases about 24 tons of hosiery waste as raw material **per year** from different suppliers located mainly in Dhaka district.
> 2. The business purchases about 20 tons of raw materials from different suppliers located mainly in Dhaka district **per year**.

Comment: I don't have enough evidence to give a fully-fledged answer, but the first definitely sounds more natural and less confusing.

Comment: Neither is to my liking, I'd place it where it rightly belongs. "The business purchases **about 20 tons per year** of raw materials from different suppliers located mainly in Dhaka district." It also depends on the broader context and the flow of narrative.

Comment: You might find more help somewhere such as English Language Leaners. Since you're here, both examples are fairly clear but “- 24 tons - of hosiery waste - as raw material - ” puts too much strain the average reader’s brain.

Try, for instance, “Per year, the business purchases…” or “The business purchases about 24 tons pre year…”

Comment: Putting it right at the end is confusing because it makes you think there are "suppliers in Dhaka per year" (which doesn't really mean anything).

Answer (score 1):

The context uses *measure units*, so I'd combine it as '**24 tons per year**' (= **24 t/year**):

> The business purchases about *24 tons per year* of hosiery waste as
>   raw material from different suppliers located mainly in Dhaka
>   district.

The less formal version '*24 tons of hosiery waste per year*' would also be OK unless it wouldn't come into conflict with the expressed here idea of *purchasing waste as raw material*.

Comment: The general idea is to try to keep the amount and period as close together as is reasonably possible.